# Is it possible to use a range as a key for a hash in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, hash, range

I'm trying to create a script to go through an index, look at each page number, and tell me what chapter of the book that entry is in. Here's an approximation of what I'm doing:

```
@chapters = {
  1 => "introduction.xhtml",
  2..5 => "chapter1.xhtml",
  6..10 => "chapter2.xhtml",
  11..18 => "chapter3.xhtml",
  19..30 => "chapter4.xhtml" }

def find_chapter(number)
  @chapters.each do |page_range, chapter_name|
    if number === page_range
      puts "<a href=\"" + chapter_name + "\page" + number.to_s + "\">" + number.to_s + </a>"
    end
  end
end
```

`find_chapter(1)` will spit out the string I want, but `find_chapter(15)` doesn't return anything. Is it not possible to use a range as a key like this?

Comment: You can use anything with a functioning [`hash`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Object.html#method-i-hash) method as a key, and since this is defined in Object, you'd almost have to go out of your way to find an object that can't be used as a key.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can use a range for Hash keys and you can look up keys very easily using `select` like this:

```
@chapters = { 1 => "introduction.xhtml", 2..5 => "chapter1.xhtml", 
              6..10 => "chapter2.xhtml", 11..18 => "chapter3.xhtml",                                         
              19..30 => "chapter4.xhtml" } 

@chapters.select {|chapter| chapter === 5 }
 #=> {2..5=>"chapter1.xhtml"}
```

If you only want the chapter name, just add `.values.first` like this:

```
@chapters.select {|chapter| chapter === 9 }.values.first
 #=> "chapter2.xhtml"
```

Comment: I like this answer the best - seems the most idiomatic. +1

Comment: Try out ```@chapters.detect{|k,v| k === 5}.last``` because, unlike select, detect will stop iterating at the first match.

Answer (score 10):

Here's a concise way of returning just the value of the first matching key:

```
# setup
i = 17; 
hash = { 1..10 => :a, 11..20 => :b, 21..30 => :c }; 

# find key
hash.find { |k, v| break v if k.cover? i }
```

Answer (score 8):

As @Sergio Tulentsev demonstrates, it can be done. The usual way to do this however is by using a `case when` . It is a bit more flexible because you can execute code in the `then` clause and you can use an `else` part handling everything unhandled . It uses the same `===` method under the hood.

```
def find_chapter(number)
  title = case number
    when 1      then "introduction.xhtml"
    when 2..5   then "chapter1.xhtml"
    when 6..10  then "chapter2.xhtml"
    when 11..18 then "chapter3.xhtml"
    when 19..30 then "chapter4.xhtml"
    else "chapter unknown"
  end
  #optionally: do something with title
end
```

Answer (score 7):

Sure, just reverse the comparison

```
if page_range === number
```

Like this

```
@chapters = {
  1 => "introduction.xhtml",
  2..5 => "chapter1.xhtml",
  6..10 => "chapter2.xhtml",
  11..18 => "chapter3.xhtml",
  19..30 => "chapter4.xhtml" }

def find_chapter(number)
  @chapters.each do |page_range, chapter_name|
    if page_range === number
      puts chapter_name
    end
  end
end

find_chapter(1)
find_chapter(15)
# >> introduction.xhtml
# >> chapter3.xhtml
```

It works this way because `===` method on Range has special behaviour: [Range#===](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Range.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D). If you place `number` first, then [`Fixnum#===`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Fixnum.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D) is called, which compares values numerically. Range isn't a number, so they don't match.

Comment: Algorithmically speaking this is probably a whole lot slower than just expanding the ranges into multiple keys referencing the same value.

Comment: @tadman: probably. This needs to be measured. And it depends, of course, on how large your ranges are :) (expansion might cost you a lot of RAM)

Comment: Most people don't have millions of book chapters, but your point is an important thing to note.

Comment: There's also more bookkeeping to do and a higher potential for error if you expand the ranges.

Answer (score 4):

Found a forum on this [topic](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/148494). They suggest

```
class RangedHash
  def initialize(hash)
    @ranges = hash
  end

  def [](key)
    @ranges.each do |range, value|
      return value if range.include?(key)
    end
    nil
  end
end
```

Now you can use it like

```
ranges = RangedHash.new(
  1..10 => 'low',
  21..30 => 'medium',
  41..50 => 'high'
)
ranges[5]  #=> "low"
ranges[15] #=> nil
ranges[25] #=> "medium"
```

Answer (score 2):

Try out this:

```
def find_chapter(page_number)
  @chapters.select{ |chapters_key| chapters_key === page_number.to_i}.values.first
end
```

Then you simply call it like so:

```
find_chapter(10)
=> "chapter2.xhtml"


find_chapter(40)
=> nil
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.